# Separar una cadena valores en dos celdas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta cadena de caracteres

> ctransaccion=7,cmodulo=27,nombre=NOVEDADES,ruta= app/modulos/socios/mantenimiento/novedades/novedades.module#NovedadesModule

estoy separando en dos celdas
Ejemplo

Campo:   ctransaccion , cmodulo ;       Valor : 7, 27

Pero al momento de separar no me separa correctamente ninguno de los dos me separa

`Campo            Valor
ctransaccion    7,cmodulo=27,
cusuario    NHERNANDEZ,ccompan
cusuario    NHERNANDEZ,ccompan
cusuario    NHERNANDEZ,ccompan
cusuario    NHERNANDEZ,ccompan
cusuario    NHERNANDEZ,ccompan`

Lo correcto seria

`Campo            Valor
ctransaccion    7
cmodulo         27
nombre          NOVEDADES`

```
SELECT 
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(valorregistro,1,CHARINDEX('=', valorregistro)-1)) AS Campo,
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(valorregistro,CHARINDEX('=', valorregistro) + 1, (CHARINDEX(',', valorregistro) -1)-(CHARINDEX('', valorregistro) + 1)) ) AS Valor 
FROM tsegauditoriainsdel
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: podrias aclarar que te esta saliendo?

Comment: Al momento de separar me sale en campo ctransaccion pero ya no me sale los siguienes como son cmodulo  etc.. y en valor no me sale 7 sino ctransaccion= nose si ahi me explique mejor

Comment: es logico, porque tu select, selecciona solo el registro, y no genera multiples registros en la salida, si no que solo los dos campos que le pediste con los datos (y en el caso del segundo estas tomando mal los datos). usa el boton [edit], y agrega a tu pregunta la tabla origen, como sale con este query, y como queres que salga realmente

Comment: De pronto ahi esta mas claro